# Not able to fetch data from node.js API hosted on localhost using ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I created an API `http://localhost:3000/videos` which gives following output:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"spark","url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cu2E0sSlWsY&t=1339s"},{"id":2,"name":"alia","url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBYTVQ4Umdg"}]
```

I am trying to fetch this using ReactJS using following code, but it doesn't fetch the data, instead it shows "Loading..." as I mentioned in my 'if' condition:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        videos: [],
        isLoaded: false,
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

      fetch('http://localhost:3000/videos')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true, 
          videos: json,
        })
      });
    }

    render() {

      var {isLoaded, videos } = this.state;

      if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div> Loading...</div>;
      }

      else {

        return (
            <div className="App">

                <ul>
                    {videos.map(video => (
                        <li key={video.id}>
                            Name: {video.name} 
                         </li>   
                      ))};               
                </ul>

            </div>
          )
        }
    }

}

export default App;
```

I tried to replace the url with http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users and the code worked fine. It correctly fetched the name from the json. However, it doesn't work for my locally hosted APIs.

Comment: Add catch block for fetch call by using `.catch((error) => {console.log(error)})` and let us know what the error is. It seems the issue is due to CORS. If that is the case you need to add CORS headers because node api is on different port than the react site.

Comment: Try adding `.catch(console.error)` to your `fetch` call, I presume it's failing. Most like a CORS problem based on different ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe and almost its a CORS problem so in your backend install CORS by `npm i cors --save-dev` then use it in your server:

```
const cors = require('cors');
......
app.use(cors());
.......
app.listen(PORT , ()=> console.log('server on'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If Your frontend and backend are not communicating there is 0.9 probability of CORS issue.
Simply put his code on Your server side.

```
        app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });
```

Hope this will help.